# Can I add a marker to an ArrayList and a HashMap at the same time?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have this code that is working exactly as I want. I mean I have a map fragment that displays 5 marker category, I can filter them as I want by category and everything works fine. As you might observe marker 1 and marker 8 will appear in more than one category. Here is the code and I will continue my problem afterwards:

```
        Boolean mSetCameraPosition;
        Boolean checkBox1Checked, checkBox2Checked, checkBox3Checked,     checkBox4Checked, checkBox5Checked;
        private int mapTypeSelected;
        CheckBox cbAllDay, cbBefore12, cbBetween1216, cbBetween1620, ccbAfter20;
        AlertDialog dialog;
        List<Marker> firstCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marker> secondCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marker> thirdCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marker> fourthCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Marker> fifthCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mapTypeSelected = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
            mSetCameraPosition = true;

        } else {
            mapTypeSelected = savedInstanceState.getInt("the_map_type", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mSetCameraPosition = false;



  @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        if (mSetCameraPosition) {
            initialLocation(TOULOUSE_LAT, TOULOUSE_LNG, 12);

        }
        mMap.setMapType(mapTypeSelected);

 if (initialMarkers) {
            addMarkers2Map();
        }

  public void addMarkers2Map() {

        // Markers location

        LatLng marker1 = new LatLng(43.607044, 1.450307);
        LatLng marker2= new LatLng(43.571505, 1.417759);
        LatLng marker3= new LatLng(43.607469, 1.447162);
        LatLng marker4= new LatLng(43.600723, 1.455917);
        LatLng marker5= new LatLng(43.604892, 1.476562);
        LatLng marker6= new LatLng(43.604496, 1.474924);
        LatLng marker7= new LatLng(43.604781, 1.474502);

        // Markers All day long
        firstCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker1).title("First Place ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 8.30 - 22.30")));

        // Markers Before 12 PM
        secondCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker2).title("Second Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 10.30 - 11.30")));

        // Markers Between 12-16
        thirdCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker3).title("Third Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 15.30 - 16.30")));
        thirdCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker4).title("Fourth Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 15.00 - 16.00")));

        // Markers Between 16-20
        fourthCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker5).title("Fifth Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 15.30 - 16.30")));
        fourthCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker6).title("Sixth Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 16.30 - 17.30")));
        fourthCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker7).title("Seventh Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 18.30 - 19.30")));
        fourthCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker8).title("Eighth Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 17.30 - 18.30\nHH:21.30 - 22.30")));


        // Markers After 20
        fifthCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker8).title("Eighth Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 17.30 - 18.30\nHH:21.30 - 22.30")));
        fifthCategoryList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker1).title("First Place").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 8.30 - 22.30")));


  public void filterTheMarkers(View view) {


        if (dialog == null){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View checkBoxView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.markers_filtering, null);
        builder.setView(checkBoxView);
        cbAllDay = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        if (checkBox1Checked != null) {
            cbAllDay.setChecked(checkBox1Checked);

        }
        cbBefore12 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        if (checkBox2Checked != null) {
            cbBefore12.setChecked(checkBox2Checked);

        }
        cbBetween1216 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        if (checkBox3Checked != null) {
            cbBetween1216.setChecked(checkBox3Checked);

        }
        cbBetween1620 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        if (checkBox4Checked != null) {
            cbBetween1620.setChecked(checkBox4Checked);

        }
        ccbAfter20 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        if (checkBox5Checked != null) {
            ccbAfter20.setChecked(checkBox5Checked);

        }

        dialog = builder.create();


    }

        dialog.show();
    }

  public void displaySelectedMarkers(View view) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.i("TAG", "All Day " + cbAllDay.isChecked() + " Before 12 " + cbBefore12.isChecked() + " Between 12-16 " + cbBetween1216.isChecked() + " Between 16-20" + cbBetween1620.isChecked() + " After 20 " + ccbAfter20.isChecked());
        //according these check boxes status execute your code to show/hide markers


        if (cbAllDay.isChecked() && cbBefore12.isChecked() && cbBetween1216.isChecked() && cbBetween1620.isChecked() && ccbAfter20.isChecked()) {
            // show all markers
            for (Marker marker : firstCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            for (Marker marker : secondCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            for (Marker marker : thirdCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            for (Marker marker : fourthCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            for (Marker marker : fifthCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
        } else if (cbAllDay.isChecked() && !cbBefore12.isChecked() && !cbBetween1216.isChecked() && !cbBetween1620.isChecked() && !ccbAfter20.isChecked()) {
            // show only All Day Markers
            for (Marker marker : firstCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            for (Marker marker : secondCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
            for (Marker marker : thirdCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
            for (Marker marker : fourthCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
            for (Marker marker : fifthCategoryList) {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
//....and it goes like this for a while until I finish all the possibilities
```

Now what I want to do is open a new activity for every markers info window clicked so the solution that I found is to add all the markers to a HashMap and give a name for every marker so that I can add it to the HashMap and to the ArrayList, like this:

```
private Map<Marker, Class> allMarkersMap = new HashMap<>();
Marker markerMarker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker1).title("BAR ACASA").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker)).snippet("HH: 8.30 - 22.30"));

firstCategoryList.add(markerMarker1);
allMarkersMap.put(markerMarker1, Marker1.class);
```

Now on onMapReady I am adding this code and I create a class for every marker Marker1.java, Marker2.java.....:

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(MyOnInfoWindowClickListener);
GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener MyOnInfoWindowClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Class cls = allMarkersMap.get(marker);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cls );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Everything works fine for the markers that appear only in one category, but for the ones that are in more than one category the filter is not working anymore, displaying only the markers that were last added to the HashMap(hopefully you understand what I am saying here).

So, can I do this and still have my filter functioning? As I am imagining that what is happening is the fact that once I define a marker and put it in the Arraylist it moves the marker there, and afterwards when I put it in the HashMap it moves it again to the HashMap so when I filter for arraylists the marker is not in the list anymore...
What would be the best solution for my info window opening a different activity for each marker displayed?

Comment: just pass paramter(different each time according to marker click ) on on marker click and keep activity same. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write to much code for my solution because I think it would be better for you to write it and I think the idea behind it is more important than the code itself.

First of all, a small suggestion  for you, whenever you start developing UI things that display information, try to find a generic description or a rule that describes the information that will be displayed. When you found that rule/description it means you found a `model` class.
I strongly suggest to use custom classes created by you that hold information required for your UI.

Now back to your example, from what I understand, you have markers that would be added to a category and based on that category you display them on the map.
What I would do I would create a custom class, called let's say `MyAwesomeMarker` that has a `Marker` member and a `ArrayList<String> category`.

Something like this:

```
public class MyAwesomeMarker {
   private Marker mMarker;
   private List<String> mMarkerCategories; // here you can mark if a marker is in more than one categories.
   // constructors
   public MyAwesomeMarker(Marker marker, String category) {
     mMarker = marker;
     mMarkerCategories = new ArrayList<String>();
     mMarkerCategories.add(category);            
   }

   public void addNewCategory(String category) {
      if(category != null && !mMarkerCategorie.contains(category)) {
         mMarkerCategories.add(category);
      }
   }

   public void toggleMarkerIfHasCategory(String theCategory) {
       for(String category : mMarkerCategories) {
           if(category.equals(theCategory) {
                   marker.setVisible(true);
           }
           else {
                 marker.setVisible(false);
           }

       }
   }

   // setters getters 
}
```

Then in your main class I would have a list of `MyAwesomeMarker`, let's call it `myMarkers`

Now you want to display all the markers that are in a category named `awesomness`.

```
for(MyAwesomeMarker marker : myMarkers) {
       marker.toggleMarkerIfHasCategory("awesomness");
}
```

Now the only thing you have to do, is generate your lit of custom markers and you're done.

Comment: I will certainly give your suggestion a try tomorrow. I agree with the fact that it's better if I write the code as that way I will understand better what I'm doing. I didn't understood what you were trying to tell me here "whenever you start developing UI things that display information, try to find a generic description or a rule that describes the information that will be displayed. When you found that rule/description it means you found a model class." (try to find a generic description or a rule where? I am quite new with all this and I would really appreciate a more detailed explanation)

Comment: I also do not know how to "private List<String> mMarkerCategories; // here you can mark if a marker is in more than one categories." This will be a list of strings named mMarkerCategories, so in this case it can contain either the categories either the markers? Sorry but I don't understanding exactly what you're explaining

Comment: And just to clarify what I am trying to do: I am adding some markers on the map. This markers will always be there. I group the markers into 5 categories. Some markers will be part of more than one category. The markers will be filtered by category and will be displayed accordingly, but the other markers, the ones that are not part of that category will not be deleted just  set to not visible. This way I want to add the markers to the map only one time and manipulate them afterwards through the filter process.

Comment: @First comment: What I wanted to say is create objects that contains data that you want to display, in order to do this you have to find a rule (eg. you have a Marker with category => a custom class that has a marker variable and a category variable). Second the mMarkers will contain categories, because your categories are strings. Third comment, it's handled in toggle method.

Comment: OK, in theory I understand what you're saying, unfortunately I need to read more documentation in order to be able to do it also practically. I started this a few months ago, and I belive I am still missing a lot of important concepts. If you could provide an exact code solution, I will start from it in order to get a better grasp of the concept. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not want you to think that I do not appreciate your answer, except that  it took me a long time to reach the stage that I am now in my app and I would like to see how it is done starting from my code. I am pretty sure that are a lot of ways to do this, and for sure the way that I started it is not the best way but at least I understand everything that I've done up till now.